# What is the impact of insufficient RAM on SSIS lookup's full cache mode?

Tags: ssis

What is the impact of insufficient RAM on SSIS lookup's full cache mode? Does the package fail? Or does it continue to run by paging to disk (which is the default behavior when system runs out of memory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page to disk is the answer.

Which can get to be right hilarious if say someone specifies a Lookup transformation should use the full cache against, I don't know, maybe the `Transactions` table. And you select the table in the drop down even though you only need to test whether a row exists. And you work for a Mutual Funds company and there's just a *few* rows in that table, per fund, per day for twenty plus years. If you have not specified where the temporary file location resides for your SSIS package, you could spool to disk, which will be the C drive, and fill up the OS drive and the machine then crashes.

Hypothetically speaking.